# TypeORMError "Driver not Connected" when calling main method

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am using `NestJS` and it's integrated `typeorm` framework to run a simple program:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/axios": "^3.0.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.2.9",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^4.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.9",
    "typeorm-extension": "^2.1.9"
}
```

My main module `app.module.ts` is declared as such:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            envFilePath: [ '.env.local' ],
            isGlobal: true,
            validationSchema: CoreJoi.object({
                DB_DATABASE: CoreJoi.string().required(),
                DB_HOST: CoreJoi.string().required(),
                DB_PASSWORD: CoreJoi.string().required(),
                DB_PORT: CoreJoi.number().required().default(5432),
                DB_SYNCHRONIZE: CoreJoi.boolean().default(false),
                DB_USERNAME: CoreJoi.string().required(),
            }),
        }),
        DatabaseModule,
        HttpModule
     ],
     providers: [AppService],
     controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The `database.module.ts` is where the data source is initialized, using an asynchronous function to fetch the credentials from a Secret Manager:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ ConfigModule ],
      inject: [ ConfigService ],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get<string>('DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get<number>('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get<string>('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: async () => {
          const secretManagerService = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

          const [accessResponse] = await secretManagerService.accessSecretVersion({
            name: configService.get<string>('DB_PASSWORD'),
          });

          return accessResponse.payload.data.toString();
        },
        database: configService.get<string>('DB_DATABASE'),
        synchronize: configService.get<boolean>('DB_SYNCHRONIZE'),
        autoLoadEntities: true,
      }),
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ /* my entities */ ]),
  ],
  providers: [ DatabaseService ],
  exports: [ DatabaseService ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

---

The problem occurs when I try to start my server. The `main.ts` goes as follow:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);

  const appService = app.get(AppService);

  await appService.process();

  await app.close();
}
bootstrap();
```

Launching this gives me the following error when we're hitting the point where I need to use the database:

```
throw new TypeORMError("Driver not Connected")
              ^
TypeORMError: Driver not Connected
    at PostgresQueryRunner.connect (...)
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (...)
```

---

If I try to expose a controller and call and endpoint which calls
`appService.process()`, for instance like this:

```
@Post()
launchProcessing(): Promise<void> {
    return this.appService.process();
}
```

*Everything works fine*.

---

How do I solve this problem ? Is there something amiss in my setup ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Turns out, you must first manually get the Module before fetching the Service, despite the `NestFactory.create(YourModule)` being called.

The method `INestApplication<>.select(YourModule)` allows you to do so.

The following code runs correctly:

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    // app.listen(3000) literally does nothing in my use case so I kicked it out

    const appModule = app.select(AppModule);
    const appService = appModule.get(AppService);

    await appService.process();

    await app.close();
}

bootstrap();
```

---

Bonus, here is a refactoring I performed on my code once it runs correctly:

```
// async was not needed for me here, but you could keep it with await
function boostrap()  {
    NestFactory.create(AppModule).then(app => {

    // Contrary to create() or get(), select() does not return a Promise<>
    // My process() method does, tho
    app.select(AppModule).get(AppService).process().then(() => {
        console.log('Processing done !');

        // Don't forget to close your app (if needed) ;)
        app.close();
    });
});

bootstrap();
```